# Dynamically identify/locate HTML tables within a page?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, vb.net, .net-2.0

Admin users can add HTML content to a website via a CMS textbox control.

When this content is displayed to a website visitor, I'd like to identify the presence of a HTML table (added by a Admin user using the CMS) and display an option for visitors to export that table.

I can handle the exporting, but identifying the HTML tables has me stumped.
Can anyone provide me with some direction?  This website is using ASP.NET 2.0/VB.NET.

Comment: Is your intention to do this client or server side?

Answer (score 1):

Give them a specific ID and target this id using Javascript acting on the DOM.

http://www.w3schools.com/htmldom/dom_obj_table.asp

Comment: How do I find the tables to assign them a specific ID?

Comment: getElementsByTagNames('table');

http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/getElementsByTagNames.html

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this work client side you can do so with JavaScript using getElementsByTagName('table').

http://www.w3schools.com/HTMLDOM/met_doc_getelementsbytagname.asp